# How to create nested formgroup, model based reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `User` form of reactive forms and I have used `RxFormBuilder` from `@rxweb` package , I have a user model class which contains `UserInfo` object, how can I use it as a nested `formgroup`?

model.ts:

```
import {prop,propArray } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"
export class UserInfo{
   @prop()
   cityId: number 

   @prop()
   countryId: number;
}

export class User{
 @prop()
 userId: string;

 @prop()
 password: string;

@prop()
securityQuestion: string;

 @prop()
 userInfo : UserInfo;

}
```

component.ts:

```
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    userInfoFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userInfoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.formGroup(User);
    }
}
```

I want to use `UserInfo` object in the user model as a nested `formgroup`. How can I create nested `formgroup`?

Here is a stackblitz link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-nested-formgroup-using-model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [an example](https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/blob/812e3bf9727ff0a47536e3f316f5fbe569d7a35e/test/reactive-form-validators/decorator/propObject.spec.ts) from `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` you should decorate you `userInfo` property with `@propObject` decorator:

```typescript
import { propObject} from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators";

export class User {
  ...

  @propObject(UserInfo)
  userInfo: UserInfo;
}
```

And also initialize `FormGroup` like:

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
    let user = new User();
    user.userInfo = new UserInfo();
    this.userInfoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.formGroup(user);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-nested-formgroup-using-model-byr4ae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-info%2Fadd%2Fuser-info-add.component.ts)**